# Populating a table with array values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have created a reaction tester game from a tutorial I was following but I wanted to add to it as practice except I can't figure out how to populate the table with users top 10 results. I am storing the results in an array. The idea is the user will play the game until they want to get their 10 best scores, they will press the button and the table will populate with their results from the array. The max size of the table will be 10 but it can go from 0 to 10 in size, if the user only plays 5 times the table will only create 5 rows etc.

The table will have 2 columns, 1st one is for the ordering 1st-10th. 2nd is for the best times.

```
<table id="resultsTable" border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>Position</th>
       <th>Best time</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have created the array to store the unordered values.

```
var newArray = new Array();
```

Once the shape gets clicked I push the result onto the end of the array, I also added a count to keep track of how many go there are.

```
var count = 0;

// When the shape is clicked

document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";

    //increments when user clicks the shapes
    count++;

    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = (end -start)/1000;
    document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
    document.getElementById("clickNumber").innerHTML = count;

    appearAfterDelay();

    newArray.push(count, timeTaken);
}
```

Once the button gets pressed I create a clone of newArray and sort it, I want to keep the unordered array separate.

```
var clone = newArray.slice(0);

//sorts the best times
clone.sort();
```

I am trying to implement this nested for loop to display the values into the table but this is where I get stuck.

```
var increment = 1; //Global variable


//once i is less than the count it keeps going. Because its sorted first best 10 will be at front, don't need to go any further.
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var newRow = table.insertRow(count);
    for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){
        if (increment <= 10) {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = clone[i][j];
            increment ++;
        }else{
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

I have attached a link of the code in action below, Any help in getting this to work would be great thanks.

[Live reaction tester link](https://codepen.io/mono92/pen/qMyZPp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you need in order to sort this out.

First, you haven't defined the variable you are using to insert rows in your results table. If you set up your `table` html like this:

```
<table id="resultsTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Best time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can select the `tbody` section (where you want to display results below your table heading) like this:

```
var results = document.getElementById('results');
```

Then, there are a variety of ways to display the results you are looking for, but here is one that is generally in line with what you are attempting to do. You are misunderstanding how [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) work, the code example below just uses the `-1` index to insert the rows and cells at the end. Also, your `clone` array is not an array of arrays, so you can't access the values with the syntax you are using and there is really no reason for the nested loops. Eliminated the use of your `increment` variable because you can just use the iterator to break the loop after 10 results are displayed. Also added `results.innerHTML = ''` before the loop to clear the results before you display the new (likely different) top 10 times on subsequent clicks (there are better ways to remove the html, but want to keep the code example below focused on the loop where most of your issues are).

```
results.innerHTML = '';
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  var newRow = results.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(-1);
  cell1.innerHTML = i + 1;
  cell2.innerHTML = clone[i];
  if (i === 9) {
    break;
  } 
}
```

With the above changes, you don't need to include your `count` values in `newArray` as it will muddy your results with false data. So change `newArray.push(count, timeTaken)` to `newArray.push(timeTaken)`.

Also, the js sort function compares array values as strings by default. To compare numerical values, you need to pass a function to `sort`, like `clone.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;})` to sort values in ascending order.

Last, it might help you to paste your js into a validator like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) because I think you may have another error or two in your codepen based on my quick scan (won't hurt to check).

Comment: Thanks for replying, this has helped me a lot and has nearly fully solved my issue. The only issue with the code above is that it is overwriting the table head (thead) elements and replacing with the values. I have tried amending the code to stop that from happening but I am having no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the `table.innerHTML = ''` is removing all of the html for your `table` child elements including the header, so you could adjust your `table` html to include a `thead` with your current headings and a `tbody` in your table and then select and clear just the `tbody` html when new results are displayed. Make sense?

Comment: I got it. I gave the tbody of the table and id of tbody and instead of                  
       var table = document.getElementById('resultsTable');                                   
I defined it like so                                                                                          
       var table = document.getElementById('tbody');                                                Is this the way you were talking about doing ?

Comment: @mono92 that works. Edited the answer to explain a bit more and it ends up in more or less the same place that you did already.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One quick question i'm noticing one small issue that I hadn't seen before and I think its down to my sorting. For certain times like 2.65s, it's saying that 10.385s is quicker once sorted. I'm thinking that the sort function is getting mixed up with something? Is there any reason why this would be happening or is it that I am calling my sort in the wrong place?

Comment: @mono92 [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) compares array values as strings. To sort numerically, you need to pass a simple function like `clone.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;});`. Also, if you haven't already, you should change `newArray.push(count, timeTaken)` to `newArray.push(timeTaken)` so your counts don't get mixed in with the values tracking the time to each click and mess up your results (I will edit my answer momentarily to reflect both of these items).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that's how the sort was done, it makes sense. So what you are saying is I will have to create a function that takes in 2 inputs and returns the result is it? I actually spotted that already, that solved one of the issues I had but this I couldn't fix. I apologize for asking so many questions on this, its just I am new and have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: @mono92 short answer is that you can copy and paste the `sort` code from the edited answer and it will perform the sort you want, but you should click on the `sort` link in my previous comment and read through the examples because I think it will help you understand how to use the function in the future.

Comment: Again I got it, decided to look that up myself, clone.sort((a, b) => a -b); is what I used and it seems to work perfectly now and I understand why too. Thanks very much for the assist a